# ArrayList for loop returning incorrect values for object member variables

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a function that will recieve one object and the ArrayList it is contained in. The object that has been passed should have it's `relationship` value incremented by 10 and every other object in the ArrayList should have their `relationship` values incremented by 3. I've rewritten my code multiple times but I'm still unable to output the values I want. Below, I have included my functions, the test method I am using, and the output values. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? (Edit: Expected values in comments next to test methods.)

**from MainTest.java**

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    baratheons = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Robert", 15));
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Renly", -5));
    baratheons.add( new Lord("Stannis", 30));

    starks = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    starks.add( new Lord("Robb", -60));
    starks.add( new Lord("Eddard", 0));
    starks.add( new Lord("Jon", 90));
}

@AfterEach
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    baratheons = null;
    starks = null;
}


public void testGratefulLord() {
    int x = baratheons.get(0).getRelationship();
    System.out.println("\n This marks the start of testGratefulLord -");
    baratheons.get(0).giveFief(baratheons, baratheons.get(0));
    assertEquals(baratheons.get(0).getRelationship(), (x+=10));
    //expected value for Robert.getRelationship is 25 
}

@Test
public void testAlliesApprove() {
    int x = starks.get(1).getRelationship();
    System.out.println("\n This marks the start of testAlliesApprove -");
    starks.get(0).giveFief(starks, starks.get(0));
    assertEquals(starks.get(1).getRelationship(), x+3);
    //expected value for Eddard.getRelationship is 3
}
```

**from Lord.java**

```
public void giveFief(ArrayList<Lord> arrayListLord, Lord lordGivenFief) {
    lordGivenFief.relationship += 10;

    ArrayList<Lord> temp = new ArrayList<Lord>();
    temp.add(lordGivenFief);
    arrayListLord.remove(lordGivenFief);

    for (Lord l : arrayListLord) { 
        l.setRelationship(relationship+=3);
        System.out.printf("%s has a relationship of %d. \n", l.lordName, l.relationship);
    }
}
```

**Output Values**

This marks the start of testGratefulLord -

Renly has a relationship of 28.

Stannis has a relationship of 31.

This marks the start of testAlliesApprove -

Eddard has a relationship of -47.

Jon has a relationship of -44.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My bad, I've added them in an edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every other object in the ArrayList should have their relationship values incremented by 3

But that's not what you're doing. When you call

```
baratheons.get(0).giveFief(baratheons, baratheons.get(0))
```

both `this` and `lordGivenFief` refers to `Lord("Robert", 15)`.

Your list starts with

```
arrayListLord: Lord("Robert", 15)
               Lord("Renly", -5)
               Lord("Stannis", 30)
```

You then increment "Robert" by 10 and remove it from the list:

```
temp:          Lord("Robert", 25)

arrayListLord: Lord("Renly", -5)                
               Lord("Stannis", 30)
```

In your loop, you then do `l.setRelationship(relationship+=3)`, which is logically the same as

```
this.relationship = this.relationship + 3
l.setRelationship( this.relationship )
```

So after first iteration, values are

```
temp:          Lord("Robert", 28)

arrayListLord: Lord("Renly", 28)                
               Lord("Stannis", 30)
```

So after second iteration, values are

```
temp:          Lord("Robert", 31)

arrayListLord: Lord("Renly", 28)                
               Lord("Stannis", 31)
```

Giving you the output you see:

```
This marks the start of testGratefulLord -
Renly has a relationship of 28.
Stannis has a relationship of 31.
```

If you want to increment the value of each object by 3, you should have done

```
l.setRelationship(l.getRelationship() + 3)
```

That way, result would have been

```
temp:          Lord("Robert", 25)

arrayListLord: Lord("Renly", -2)                
               Lord("Stannis", 33)
```